# Issue with discord authorization

Tags: discord, discord-buttons, discord-interactions

[Discord issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS3f9.png)

Help needed guys, I want to give authorization to app linked to discord while granting access I click on authorize button. this made no reaction I tried severe times but got no response. I would really be grateful if anyone can put put a solution through. Thanks